# Does TDengine support functions in where clause?

Tags: sql, database, tdengine

I tried to query data in TDengine with the following sql clause:

```
SELECT * from TABLE where COLUMN < FUNCTION();
```

and I got illegal condition expression error.

Does anyone know if using function in where condition is illegal usage in SQL convention or I need to resort to other syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Using function in where condition is illegal. Maybe it will be supported later.